# AngularJS filter infinite digest

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I have a filter:

```
filter('keys', [function() {
  return function(obj) {
    if (angular.isObject(obj)) {
      return Object.keys(obj);
    }
  };
}])
```

This filter is then used with an object to get the keys. I'm using it like this:

`<directive data="{test: 1, test1: 2, test2: 3} | keys"></directive>`

And I get an infinite digest error. Why?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand the issue with this piece of code. What is `directive` here?

Comment: An AngularJS directive or really any element.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue in a plunker

Comment: Wouldn't Angular create fresh object instance every time the expression is evaluated? Do you have `$watch` on that expression?

Comment: @PavelHoral It doesn't seem that obvious. defining object expression in the view will not have any of those effect as you mentioned. You can just try it yourself. It has to be contributed by something else as well. Here you got one example http://plnkr.co/edit/HRUoze2GvMVsWTwGTnr6?p=preview

Comment: Your filter function is fine, I think the problem in how you pass the data to the directive, What's in the directive?

Comment: Yeah the question is unclear. Voting for closure.

Comment: @teleaziz the filter function passes in the data as an array, but it's not throwing the infinite digest from the directive, because when I remove the filter, I don't get any error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that each loop creates a whole new object to be filtered. Your filter creates a new object, in the view, which in return triggers the digest to use the filter on the new object and so on.

You should define your object in a controller to prevent a new object being created, in the view, in each loop.

Even better would be to use your filter in the controller, this will prevent the filter being used in each loop.